# How to debug a .dll?

Tags: c#

I have a .dll attached to my project(I made the .dll). I have in the .dll project configuration set to "Active (Debug)".

I even deleted the .dll then added break points to the .dll code and rebuilt it and added back to my project and I still can't go inside the .dll and debug it.

I not sure what I am missing?

Comment: What does the dll do?  What uses the dll?  If nothing is executing code using the stuff in the dll, you can't debug against it.

Comment: The dll is a paypal library I made. I can debug up to the line where it calls a class inside the .dll. Once I get to this line I try to step into the method but it just goes over it and the variable that is returned in a "SuccessWithWarning". So something failed but I need to see inside it to see what failed.

Comment: Is the .pdb file present at the location where you are running the application that is calling the .dll?

Comment: .pdb file? I am not sure what that is.

Comment: can't you just add that project that this DLL is made from to your current solution and compile that library code with your current solution? Change your reference (temporarily) to the included project, and you can easily step into your library code.....

Comment: chobo2: The PDB (Program Debug) file contains the information the VS debugger needs to hook up the binary DLL to the source code.  For example, it maps the compiled instructions to source file names and line numbers, so that VS can figure out which file to display when you step into a method and how far in the compiled code to advance when you step over a source code line.  (I'm simplifying but hopefully this gives you the idea.)  The PDB file is by default created alongside the DLL in debug builds.

Comment: Hmm maybe the PDB file was not being copied over when I did a manual copy it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place a breakpoint on the consuming code that calls into the .dll. When your project breaks there, step into the call (F11, by default).

Otherwise, I'd strongly suggest importing the project from which the .dll is built into the solution of the project that is attempting to consume it.  This is the arrangement that makes VS happiest and causes the least headaches from versioning, switching between solutions, etc.

You'll have no difficulty debugging then.

Comment: +1 yup, definitely add that project that makes up that DLL into your current solution, and off you go stepping into it no problem! :-)

Comment: It is in one solution but I guess the PBD was not being copied over or something when I moved it manually it worked.

Comment: having the DLL project was not necessary for me - stepping in is all you need - as long as the PDB lies next to the DLL